# CTD in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My macro is causing excel to crash to desktop with no debug or error message, the whole application shuts down, closing any open instances of excel.

The code that I've written so far is pretty light, so I have no idea what is causing the crash.

The crash appears to occur after `StartGame()` has finished. I assume it's being caused by the Timer which runs Main() every 50ms as the CTD exclusively happens after End Sub in `StartGame()`.

I've included all the code below.

**Main Module**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub StartGame()

    InitialiseGame
    InitialiseTimer

    GameRunning = True

End Sub

Public Sub Main()

    If GameInput.TabIsPressed Then TerminateTimer
    If Not GameRunning Then Exit Sub

    Graphics.DrawSquare

End Sub

Private Sub InitialiseGame()

    Set GameInput = New ClassGameInput
    Set Graphics = New ClassGraphics
    Set Square = New ClassSquare

End Sub
```

**Timer Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND As Integer = 1000
Private Const GAME_TICKS_PER_SECOND As Integer = 20

Private GameTimerID As Long

Public Sub InitialiseTimer()

    Dim GameTimerInterval As Double

    GameTimerInterval = MILLISECONDS_IN_SECOND / GAME_TICKS_PER_SECOND

    Sleep (500)

    GameTimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, GameTimerInterval, AddressOf Main)

End Sub

Public Sub TerminateTimer()

    If GameTimerID <> 0 Then
        KillTimer 0, GameTimerID
        GameTimerID = 0
        GameRunning = False
    End If

    Set GameInput = Nothing
    Set Graphics = Nothing
    Set Square = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Public Declarations Module**

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr) As Long
    Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#End If

Public Const BORDER_START_X As Integer = 4
Public Const BORDER_START_Y As Integer = 4
Public Const BORDER_END_X As Integer = 185
Public Const BORDER_END_Y As Integer = 73

Public Const SQUARE_SIZE As Integer = 10
Public Const SQUARE_COLOUR As Long = rgbLightBlue

Public GameRunning As Boolean
Public GameInput As ClassGameInput
Public Graphics As ClassGraphics
Public Square As ClassSquare
```

**Class GameInput**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function UpIsPressed() As Boolean
    UpIsPressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyUp) <> 0)
End Function
Public Function DownIsPressed() As Boolean
    DownIsPressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyDown) <> 0)
End Function
Public Function LeftIsPressed() As Boolean
    LeftIsPressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyLeft) <> 0)
End Function
Public Function RightIsPressed() As Boolean
    RightIsPressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyRight) <> 0)
End Function
Public Function TabIsPressed() As Boolean
    TabIsPressed = (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyTab) <> 0)
End Function
```

**Class Graphics**

```
Option Explicit

Const COL_WIDTH As Double = 0.83
Const ROW_HEIGHT As Double = 7.5

Private GameCanvas As Range

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    With shtGame

        .cmdGo.Visible = False
        .Cells.Columns.ColumnWidth = COL_WIDTH
        .Cells.Rows.RowHeight = ROW_HEIGHT
        .EnableSelection = xlNoSelection
        .Protect AllowFormattingCells:=True
        .Cells.Interior.Color = rgbDarkSlateGrey
        Set GameCanvas = .Range(.Cells(BORDER_START_Y, BORDER_START_X), .Cells(BORDER_END_Y, BORDER_END_X))
        GameCanvas.Interior.Pattern = xlNone

    End With

End Sub

Public Sub DrawSquare(SquareX As Integer, SquareY As Integer)

    Dim SquareRange As Range

    With shtGame

        Set SquareRange = .Range(.Cells(SquareY, SquareX), .Cells(SquareY + SQUARE_SIZE - 1, SquareX + SQUARE_SIZE - 1))
        SquareRange.Interior.Color = SQUARE_COLOUR

    End With


End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

    With shtGame

        .cmdGo.Visible = True
        .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
        .Unprotect
        .Cells.Clear

    End With

End Sub
```

**Class Square**

```
Option Explicit

Private SquareX As Integer
Private SquareY As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    SquareX = BORDER_START_X
    SquareY = BORDER_START_Y

End Sub
```

Sorry for the big fat code dump, but I really have no idea what is causing the problem!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's CTD? and try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)/[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first by remove unnecessary components until you get to the part that causes the problem

Comment: Have you checked if it still crashes on a longer delay? Is it possible that something hasn't finished running before it refreshes?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc CTD is crash to desktop (i.e. excel crashes completely with no error message)

Comment: @CLR no I haven't but that is worth trying!

Answer (score 0):

The CTD was being caused by missing arguments when calling DrawSquare().

I had incorrectly missed the x and y co-ordinates of the sub.

Normally, the compiler would pick-up on this error, however as the Main module was being called automatically by my timer no error checking was taking place.

```
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
```